# Round-Trip Editing with WebDav for Domino

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, webdav, xpages-extlib

With the Round-trip Editing Library for Domino [WebDAV for IBM Domino](https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/WebDAV%20for%20IBM%20Domino) on openntf which should enable me to open an attachment, such as Microsoft Word, edit, and save it back to the server.

I have configure my server with the necessary information but find it difficult to run the WebDocOpenSetup and the WebDocOpen.exe file on my 64bit window system, any idea how i could go about this?

Comment: You should edit your question as it seems it belongs to the WebDAV project on OpenNTF and not explicitly to XPages - or you have to clarify it a bit https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/WebDAV%20for%20IBM%20Domino

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this piece of code, so let me explain a few of the challenges you will face:

- Windows will open anything that starts with http(s) using a webbrowser and not an app. It happily ignores file extension. Thus a different protocol was needed. I opted for `webdav://` (like you have `skype://`, `notes://`, `sap://` )
- the helper application (on Windows - or the script for OS/X Linux) simply reacts on that protocol. The installer simply creates the needed registry entries. You could do that by hand
- When you start any office application with an URL as parameter e.g. `winword.exe https://.....doc` the webDAV mechanism kicks in as desired.
- The only thing WebDocOpenSetup does is to set some registry keys and register the `WebDocOpen.exe` as handler for the `webdav(s)://` protocol. The source code is included, you might need to recompile it for 64Bit
- the helper checks the app needed based on the extension and launches it with the url (webdav replaced with http) as parameter
- You can save yourself quite some trouble using *https* with a proper certificate. Self signed won't cut it
- There is [an article](http://www.notessensei.com/blog/2013/03/round-trip-editing-experience-in-web-browsers.html) on my blog explaining more of the background
- The registry entries [are explained here](http://www.notessensei.com/blog/2011/06/it-isnt-a-standard-if-it-isnt-broken-today-webdav.html)
- You might test with a Mac or Linux first to ensure all is working ;-)
- Even without the little helper application you can connect using Explorer webfolders (<strike>not Internet Explorer</strike>, Explorer)

Good luck!

Comment: webdav://localhost/development/FileDemo.nsf/($All)/A7BB455698A88C9FC1258018004861FA/$File/TestFile.odt

Comment: Thanks for ur response, i have configured everything it try to open but in the Repositories it empty "Domino webDAV Repository: /webdav/filedemo/"   the attachement is not in the view. In the Root field of my filedemo i have "notes:///development/FileDemo.nsf/($All)"

Comment: the error log says "Get method failed with:A webDAV Resource was not found"

Comment: the first error have been resolve but now after openning the document and try to save it prompt me the msg "Document files .... is locked for eding by Unknow User...." any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: How did you resolve the first? The server expects to be protected, no anonymous connections. Locks expire automatically after a period of time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121693/discussion-between-simon-peter-and-stwissel).

Comment: i resolve the first by seting the Load Internet configurations from Server\Internet Sites documents: on the curent server document to enable. now after opening the the document and save it. it prompt me the msg "Error saving the document..: The object cannot be created in directory."webdav://server/webdav/filedemo/1AE86876842E2B4DC1258018004E4710/doc.odt

Comment: do u have any idea i keep getting "The object cannot be created in directory". error upon saving the document

Comment: You try to edit an existing document? If yes: check the ACL. If trying to make a new one: that never had been implemented

Comment: yes am try to edit existing document and for the  ACL of db am the manager, i wont mind if u can check dis over teamviewer for me

Comment: Any special characters involved? What does the log say?

Comment: just  "Exception occurred servicing request for: /webdav/filedemo/1AE86876842E2B4DC1258018004E4710/doc.odt - HTTP Code: 500"  java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: It probably has a Line number? Or a Stacktrace?

Comment: yes, java.lang.NullPointerException  at com.ibm.xsp.webdav.WebDavServlet.service(WebDavServlet.java:317)

Comment: That's the line: `nothingToDo.setUseStream(meth.streamUsed());` - So something is not implemented or a class missing? The only way you can find out, is to run a debug session hooking the Eclipse debugger to your Domino server. Check this for instructions: http://www.slideshare.net/fiorep/domino-osgi-development

Comment: Are you sure you have all classes. In debug check line 232 - does the meth object return something not null? It depends on the presence of the method class in upper case.